# UIView in UIScrollVIew not updating views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIView layed out inside a UIScrollView. There is a method called update UI which basically updates the UI. However after the data is loaded I need to scroll down a bit to see the UI rendered.
For example, one thing I tried is to hide the UITableView in layoutSubviews and unhide it in updateUI, however I need to scroll down a bit on my UIScrollView until I see the UITableView. Why is this happening? here's my updated UI code:

This updateUI code is basically fired off when the UIScrollView is not scrolling. I have a MyViewController with a UIScrollView in it that implements UIScrollView delegate, and basically when it's not scrolling it delegates back to my UIView telling that you can update the view now.

```
- (void) updateUI
{
    self.isScrolling = NO;

    NSLog(@"UPDATE UI");

    AHMyImageData *object = self.object;

    if ([object isNotNull]){

    [self.tableView_ reloadData];

    if (![self.userProfileImage_.image isNotNull]){
        [self.userProfileImage_ setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:object.profilePicture_] andAnimate:YES];
    }

    if (![self.imageView_.image isNotNull]){
        NSString *url = [[object.image_ valueForKey:@"low_resolution"] valueForKey:@"url"];
        [self.imageView_ setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] andAnimate:YES];
    }

    if (object.userHasLiked){
        [self.likeButton_ setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-like-down.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [self.likeButton_ setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-like.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    if ([object.text_ isNotNull]){
        NSMutableAttributedString * attributedString = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:object.text_];
        [attributedString setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15]];
        [self.titleLabel_ setAttributedText:attributedString];
        [self parseTagsInComment:object.text_];
    }

    NSMutableAttributedString * usernameAttributedString = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:object.username_];
    [usernameAttributedString setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14]];
    [usernameAttributedString setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:86.0/255.0 green:134.0/255.0 blue:172.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] range:NSMakeRange(0, [object.username_ length])];
    [usernameAttributedString setTextBold:YES range:NSMakeRange(0, [object.username_ length])];

    [self.usernameLabel_ setAttributedText:usernameAttributedString];

    NSString * imageCreatorUsernameURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"userid://%@", object.userId_];
    [self.usernameLabel_ addCustomLink:[NSURL URLWithString:imageCreatorUsernameURL] inRange:NSMakeRange(0, [object.username_ length])];
    [self.usernameLabel_ setUnderlineLinks:NO];
    [self.usernameLabel_ setDelegate:self];

    [self.likesCountLabel_ setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", object.likesCount]];
    [self.commentsCountLabel_ setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", object.commentsCount]];

    if ([object.createdTime_ isNotNull]){
        [self.imageTimePostedLabel_ setText:[NSString timestampToString:object.createdTime_]];
    }


    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    [self setNeedsLayout];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"OBJECT IS NULL");
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds as though you are calling `updateUIView` from a `UIScrollViewDelegate` method - if this is true, which one?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling...

```
[self.tableView_ reloadData];
// I think you need to call reloadData only
// AFTER you do all your fun updating stuff
[self setNeedsDisplay];
[self setNeedsLayout];
```

At the very end of your function, not at the very start. Hope that helps!